# How to avoid error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined" in rxjs in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

The error that I am getting on opening the pag in angular is:

```
core.mjs:6485 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getDocumentContent')
```

I have this observable in angular component:

```
selectedDocument$ = this.store.selectedDocument$.pipe(startWith(new Log()));
```

and then in the view I have:

```
<div
    *ngIf="{
        selectedDocument: selectedDocument$ | async
    } as asyncData"
>
  
            {{ asyncData.selectedDocument.getDocumentContent() }}

</div>
```

The object created with `new Log()` will have the method, (the `getDocumentContent()` method):

```
export class Log {
    getDocumentContent() {
        return "some not important content";
    }
}
```

So I thought the method would always exist regarding angular, but it doesn't. How to solve this error?

Comment: `*ngIf="selectedDocument$ | async as selectedDocument"> {{selectedDocument.getDoc...()}}` should work

Comment: but it's not. It is causing the error.

Comment: if it is so then `selectedDocument$` stream gets undefined as a value at some point. you should check your selectors or state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the error is that your ngIf always evaluates to true even if selectedDocument$ is undefined since {selectedDocument: undefined} is not falsy.

You can validate this with this simple code `{a: undefined} ? console.log('Truthy') : console.log('Falsy')`.

More on this can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy.

Andrei's solution should therefore work.